# Binary Classification for binary dataset with DNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification

I have a dataset of binary data like this:

| age (0-9) | age (10-19) | age (20-59) | age (10-19) | gender (male) | gender (female) | ... | desired (very much) | desired (moderate) | desired (little) | desired (None) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | ... | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ... | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

the features here are the first few columns, and the target is the final 4 columns.
I'm trying here to use DNN implemented with tensorflow/keras to fit on this data.

here's my model and code:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(len(x_training)))
x = Dense(30,activation="relu")(input_layer)
x = Dense(20,activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(10,activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(5,activation="relu")(x)
output_layer = Dense(4,activation="softmax")(x)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)


model.compile(optimizer="sgd",
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_validate,y_validate))
```

and this is the history of the training:

```
Epoch 1/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 9s 4ms/step - loss: 1.3864 - accuracy: 0.2525 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2533
Epoch 2/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2518 - val_loss: 1.3864 - val_accuracy: 0.2486
Epoch 3/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2499 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2487
Epoch 4/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2515 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2539
Epoch 5/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2511 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2504
Epoch 6/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2501 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2484
Epoch 7/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2511 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2468
Epoch 8/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2509 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2519
Epoch 9/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2505 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2463
Epoch 10/10
2005/2005 [==============================] - 6s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2512 - val_loss: 1.3863 - val_accuracy: 0.2474
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f6893c61e90>
```

The accuracy and the loss doesn't change at all, I have tried the following experiments, and all gave the same result:

1. changed hidden layers activation to `sigmoid`, `tanh`
2. changed the final layer to be only one node and the `y_train` to be labeled with (1,2,3) instead of one hot encoding, and change the loss function to be sparse categorical cross entropy
3. changed the optimizer to Adam
4. changed the data to be in (-1,1) instead of (0,1)

What  am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of epochs by (at least) a factor of 10 or 100?

Comment: @Hagbard I have just tried it and still no improvements

Comment: @gobrewers14 I have tried lr=0.01, lr=0.001, and lr=0.1 and all gave the same result

Comment: What is `x_training` (used in `Input` layer) and how is it different from `x_train`?

Comment: @desertnaut `x_train` is a list of lists of length 22 of the features. and the `x_training = x_train[0]`

Comment: So, `len(x_training)` equals the number of your features (22)?

Comment: @desertnaut yes, exactly

Comment: Unfortunately, only opinions can be offered here. Stick to `relu` and your output layer as is, and experiment with the rest of the structure (both number of layers and number of nodes per layer); it would currently seem that your model is too small. Building NNs is not an exact science...

Comment: try `1e-4` or `1e-5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out some method to solve this problem, I don't think it's very scientific but actually it worked for my case

1. First I replaced every "1" in the training dataset with "0.8" and every "0" with "0.2".
2. Then I multiplied every similar features in some weight. for example if the age is "18" then the features first will be like this `[0,1,0,0]`, then apply the first step the feats will be like this `[0.2,0.8,0.2,0.2]` then multiply this array to `[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]` and sum them together to give `[0.32]` which represents the age "18" somehow.
   then by applying the previous stages to the features, I got an array of length 15 instead of 22.
3. The third stage was to apply feature size reduction using `PCA` to reduce number of features to 10.

This method was like extracting some other features from the existing features by giving it a new domain instead of the binary domain.

This gave me accuracy about `85%` which was very satisfying to me.